# HackerRank challenge: taum and b'day Explanation?

Tags: javascript

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/taum-and-bday/problem?isFullScreen=true

I'm trying to understand what the challenge is asking. I'm not asking for people to provide me solutions. I'm asking for explanation in how to calculate the minimum amount of units Taum needs to spend on gifts.

For example, in sample input:

```
5 //number of test cases
10 10 //first case
1 1 1 
5 9 //second case
2 3 4 
3 6 //third case
9 1 1 
7 7 //fourth case
4 2 1 
3 3 //fifth case
1 9 2
```

in which each case are as follows:

- The first line contains the values of integers b and w.
- The next line contains the values of integers bc , wc, and z.

in which,

- b: number of black gifts,
- w: number of white gifts,
- bc: cost of a black gift
- wc: cost of a white gift
- z: the cost to convert one color gift to the other color

**HackerRank Explanation**

> Test Case #01: Since black gifts cost the same as white, there is no benefit to converting the gifts. Taum will have to buy each gift for 1
> unit. The cost of buying all gifts will be: **b * bc + w * wc = 10 * 1 +
> 10 * 1 = 20**
>
> Test Case #02: Again, we can't decrease the cost of black or white gifts by converting colors. **Z** is too high. We will buy gifts at their
> original prices, so the cost of buying all gifts will be: **b * bc + w *
> wc = 5 * 2 + 9 * 3 = 37**.
>
> Test Case #03: Since **bc > wc + z**, we will buy **b + w = 3 + 6 = 9** white gifts at their original price of **1**. **b = 3** of the gifts must be black,
> and the cost per conversion, **z=1**. Total cost is **9 * 1 + 3 * 1 = 12**.
>
> Test Case #04: Similarly, we will buy **w = 7** white gifts at their original price, **wc = 2**. For black gifts, we will first buy white ones
> and color them to black, so that their cost will be reduced to **wc + z
> = 2 + 1 = 3**. So cost of buying all gifts will be: **7 * 3 + 7 * 2 = 35**.
>
> Test Case #05: We will buy black gifts at their original price, **bc =
> 1**. For white gifts, we will first black gifts worth **bc = 1** unit and color them to white for **z = 2** units. The cost for white gifts is
> reduced to **wc = bc + z = 2 + 1 = 3** units. The cost of buying all gifts
> will be: **3 * 1 + 3 * 3 = 3 + 9 = 12**.

What I can understand is only the first and maybe the second cases in which I can easily calculate that (black gift times black cost) plus (white gift times white cost). However, I think that what I don't understand is the **z** cost of conversion for the rest of the cases.

And in third case, what it is asking is to check if `z + wc` is less than `bc` then to get/convert white gifts, you add up `b + w` to get a number of white gifts, and do this calculation: `(w * z) + (b*z)`?

I can barely understand 4th and 5th cases. So I need an explanation on how to calculate the gifts.

Comment: What is the actual problem definition from HackerRank?

Comment: I added the link above so you can check yourself. I only put in the minimize amount of info from hacker rank challenge here.

Comment: I cannot open the link and read it. Moreover, questions are supposed to be self-contained. Right now all I see is some test cases and sample outputs, with explanation for *why* something should happen but I have no context of what the actual problem is. I can't even begin answering without a bunch of guesswork.

Comment: That's weird. Maybe this help? The first part of the video shows the problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P3o8BUwxj4w